"Interesting posts for you" - ARE NOT
On Stack Overflow, it says "Interesting posts for you" this is "Based on your viewing history and watched tags." Below is an image of the top posts picked for me today by Stack Overflow and an image of my "Watched tags".
The picked posts seem pretty representative the content I receive and is NOT what I am interested in when browsing SO and do not show a single tag on my list. I did not cherry-pick the screenshot. I just saw these and said "Why are these questions never what I am interested in" and decided to post this question.
I sometimes get curious and like to see other questions but usually I am interested in content of my "Watched tags" topics. These are "My Interests" after all.
Would it be possible to have the default page actually filter to what I am interested in or possibly it could be a tab/button that filters to only questions in the "Watched tags" list (even if these questions may be a bit less current)?
By the way, I have seen other questions like this one from Aaron Bertrand Why are most "interesting" SO questions not even remotely interesting to me? that are really old. The answers there are targeted at how to search for individual topics you are interested in. This question is a feature request to search all of the topics I am interested in.



See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/432107/these-are-not-interesting-posts-for-me
